# Identify when multiple domains are provided using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, dns

I am working on a C# form where a user provides FQDNs of two hosts and this information is later used to install some features that are only valid if the two FQDNs are on the same domain. I initially had the two hostnames and single domain name in separate fields, but it was confusing to users. Basically, I want to detect when different domains are provided in these FQDN fields. For example-

Valid input:

```
host1.domain1.example
host2.domain1.example
```

Invalid input:

```
host1.domain1.example
host2.domain2.example
```

I want to detect the invalid input, but it's trickier than I thought it would be.

Comment: Parsing domain names with regular expression will yield many edge cases that people just forget above. It is like using regular expressions on XML/HTML: not good. For `www.dk` what is the domain name? (it is `www.dk`). For `www.example.co.uk` what is the domain name (it is `example.co.uk`). etc. And no, you can not split at first dot in all generic cases (for `www.intranet.example.com` what is the domain name you want? probably `example.com`), etc. So instead: start from a list of TLD you care about, extract domains in these TLD (easy: domain = label.TLD) and then compare domains.

Comment: That's tough, as well, because these domains are typically internal, and purposely use some obscure naming, so I've seen anywhere from "cyan" to TLDs with dashes. This makes it tough to catalogue possible TLDs that users may have. As these FQDNs are going to be for AD controlled Windows hosts, I'm not worried about stripping things like `www`, but there are FQDNs that may have more than a simple `host.domain.example` format, so that's going to cause issues. I may just go back to having two fields for the hostnames and only one field for the domain and I will combine them for the FQDNs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Regex would help. It fulfills your current text reqt. You can make minor changes if you think your text will have. Let me know if you have any question.

On the example page, on the right, it has a description of what code is doing, so refer to that explanation.

**Regex:**
`(?:\w+)\.(\w+)(?:\.\w+)*\n(?:\w+)\.(?:\1)(?:\.\w+)*`

**Example:**
https://regex101.com/r/ZDG4Ba/4

Comment: Ah, apologies, the format when I first posted brought my entries up to one line. I see what you're getting at based on how the post was formatted. The edited original post should more accurately convey what I meant.

Comment: Updated my answer. Have a look and accept if it fulfils ur reqt.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I should also clarify, the FQDNs are provided in separate fields, so there isn't technically a line break between the two values, rather, they will be included as two separate variables. They are pulled from the `FQDNpri` and `FQDNsec` forms on my main.cs form like-

`string FQDNPrimary = FQDNPri.Text.ToString();
string FQDNSecondary = FQDNSec.Text.ToString();`

So I'd like to take the FQDNPrimary and FQDNSecondary strings and compare them to eachother. I can try to re-store them in a format where they are separated by a line break and test out that regex.

Comment: I believe one of the issues I will inevitably run into is when a user has additional `.` characters in their domain, as sometimes, for example, I will find something in a dev environment with an FQDN like `host.dev.domain.tld`. I think I'm just going to have the user provide the two host names, then a single separate field for the domain, and I will have them combined for the FQDN. Thank you for your suggestion, though, this is definitely on the right track.

Comment: You will not, I have updated the Regex again and updated the Example also. So your concern was if the domain comes as `abc.co.in` comes then it won't be grabbed. Now I made the changes and it will accept multiple extensions of the domain. Have a look and let me know if it works. If yes, kindly accept the answer. If not then let me know, I will see what needs to update.

Comment: Yeah, this is workable. It identifies when they are the same, I just need to store the input, then reformat them a bit for the validation regex since there's not actually a linebreak. Should be pretty straight forward, though.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Best luck!